# Vue js показать box c изображением при наведении

Tags: vue.js

Есть таблица , первым элементом стоит изображение, при наведении курсора на которое должна появляться превьюшка (изображения) напротив строки.

В проекте иcпользуется Vue.js

```
<div #id="picHolder">
...
<th>
 <img class="thumb" :src="getImg(estate.preview_image)" ref="pic" :id='estate.id' @mouseover="showthumb(estate.id)" @mouseleave="hidethumb" style="max-width: 50px; height: auto;"/>
</th>...
```

Изображение показывается по @mouseover="showthumb(estate.id)"   и скрывается @mouseleave="hidethumb"

но после прокрутки - показываются не напротив элемента =(

стили:

```
    #picHolder {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #fff no-repeat center top;
        background-size: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
```

Пробовал определить расположение элемента через свойства vm.$ref.

Первый элемент определяется правильно - последующие плавают после прокрутки

```
    methods: {

        showthumb(id){
            var target = event.target ;
            let x = 0;
            let y = 0;
            this.$refs.pic.forEach(function(data){
                if(id == data.id){
                   x = data.x;
                   y = data.y;
                }
            });
            if (target.tagName != "IMG") picHolder.style.display = 'none';
            else {
               let picHolder = document.getElementById("picHolder");

                if(picHolder != null) {
                    picHolder.style.top = (y -75 ) +"px";
                    picHolder.style.left = (x -375) +"px" ;
                    picHolder.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + target.src + ")";
                    picHolder.style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
            this.$forceUpdate();
        },

        hidethumb(){
            var picHolder = document.getElementById("picHolder");
            picHolder.style.display = 'none';
        },
```

Не подскажите, в чем может быть дело ?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: position: absolute; тут проблема, и что за прикол с #id="picHolder вместо id="picHolder в диве

Comment: эт опечатка ... в коде такого нет ) 
Да Вы правы - изменил posiiton на fixed - все норм ))
Спасибо !